# customizing UBCD with own iso's

Tags: boot, dvd, iso-image

I want to have a bootable dvd which has 2 linux mint distro's on it.
Ultimate boot cd has an option to customize the ubcd and to add your own iso's. I was trying to add my own ISO's but I am stuck because I do not know which lines to add in the custom.cfg file.

this is what is written on the customize page:

```
Adding ISO images
To add your own ISO images to UBCD, copy them to c:\ubcd-extracted\ubcd\custom. 
You can optionally compress each image using gzip (via a tool such as 7-Zip) to make them smaller. 
Then edit c:\ubcd-extracted\ubcd\custom\custom.cfg and add each ISO image to the menu.

For example:
LABEL -
MENU LABEL Windows 98
TEXT HELP
 Windows 98 boot disk
ENDTEXT
LINUX /boot/syslinux/memdisk
INITRD /ubcd/custom/win98.iso.gz
APPEND iso raw

Note that not all ISO images can be successfully booted this way. 
Real mode OSes and boot loaders that use INT13 BIOS calls will likely work, but other may not. 
For more information, refer to the memdisk documentation on ISO image support.
```

what should I add when I want to add this file for example: `linuxmint-17-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso`?

should I only change the line with `INITRD`
or also the line with `APPEND iso raw`?

The customize page does not explain this.